# Django is doubling my get parameters when I make a redirect, but only on our server

Tags: python, django, nginx

On my local test machine it works fine, but on the server it will double GET parameters.

For example, with this code:

```
return redirect('/add?c='+str(rm.id))
```

I end up at /add?c=3423?c=3423 for example.

And

```
return redirect('/add?success')
```

Gets me to /add?success?success

Does anyone know what's up?

**EDIT:** Here's my relevant line of urls.py and my nginx config

```
url(r'^add/$', 'rumors.views.add'),

server{
    listen 0.0.0.0:443 ssl;
    server_name www.****.com ****.com;
    ssl_certificate     /opt/etc/***;
    ssl_certificate_key /opt/etc/***;

    keepalive_timeout 70;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location / {
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /opt/etc/.htpasswd;
        uwsgi_pass   unix:///tmp/uwsgi_***.sock;
        include        uwsgi_params;
    }

    location /static {
            # Point this wherever the static files for your django app are stored (i.e. MEDIA_ROOT)
            alias /opt/apps/****/static;
    }

}
server {
listen 80 default_server;
server_name "";


location / {
    rewrite ^ https://****.com$request_uri permanent;
}
}
```

Comment: In your production server, is django handling this redirect as well? (not your web server)

Comment: What's your server?You'd better paste the config of your server.

Comment: It's on the testing environment of our production server where it's happening.

And what config would be helpful to see? nginx?

Comment: This looks like what happens when the actual web server handles the pattern without the trailing "/" and doesn't use the as-is url. Do you mean that its running on your production server but not doing any redirects. django is still doing the redirects?

Comment: It's running on the prod server and redirecting, but the page you end up at has the GET parameter repeated. I guess I could parse out the extra crap on the receiving page (in the above example, I would end up with 'c' being '3423?c=3423' instead of just '3423') but I wasn't thinking it would come to that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A random stab at this, without knowing enough info yet...

Its possible that what is happening, is the first request goes through the web server and on to django. Django redirects to a new url with query string, and then the request goes back through the webserver again. At that point, I think the web server is splitting up the pattern improperly. Normally when I see this, the webserver wants to see a trailing slash on the pattern to inform it that it should treat the entire url pattern raw:

So try this maybe (adding trailing slash):

```
return redirect('/add/?c='+str(rm.id))

return redirect('/add/?success')
```

Other than this, you might need to go into more detail about your production web server.

If your production server really is performing the redirect, and not django, then you should definitely look into making sure the trailing slash is present in the rule.

**Update: Based on the added nginx conf**

I think your problem might be your rewrite rule for https. Its quite possibly re-appending the query string because of a single missing `?`

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule

> If in the line of replacement arguments are indicated, then the rest
>   of the request arguments are appended to them. To avoid having them
>   appended, place a question mark as the last character:
>
> `rewrite  ^/users/(.*)$  /show?user=$1?  last;`

Try making this change in your nginx conf:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^ https://****.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Lastly, just to address your comment about the behavior of your https redirect, I think you might want to adjust that as well. I actually do something almost exactly the same on one of my servers. But I make the ssl server default, and I don't use a location directive in the port 80 server:

```
server {
        server_name www.foo.com foo.com;
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent; 
}

server {
        listen 443 default_server ssl;
        ...
}
```

Comment: Great, I'll try that and report back. Thanks

Comment: Still is doing the same thing... I added my nginx config and urls.py line to the original post

Comment: Bam, works. Thanks a lot! However, I think something must be wrong with my nginx, because the request is coming from https:// and is going to https:// so it shouldn't even be hitting that server block (the port 80 catch all). Does anything look off to you?

Comment: Nice, it works, but for some reason form submission is still going to the http:// and hitting the redirect. (I put in a dummy url for the redirect to see if it was hitting that server block) It's not a problem, it's just curious to me. I tried putting the full URL including https:// in for the action on the form and it still happens.